# How could I keep a player engaged if I can't bring his dead character back to life a for a few sessions?

Tags: gm-techniques, character-death, environmental-hazards

I have a storyline I'm writing based in an Arctic setting. The party will have to engage in a battle of survival against the elements - kind of a Napoleonic retreat from Moscow - which is likely to see some/most of the characters die.

I don't want to add wandering NPCs as I want to develop the sense of frozen wilderness and desolate isolation, so it's not workable for the players of dead characters to simply pick up a new role to play - but I don't want them sitting around the table being bored.

I am considering "ghost/shadow" ideas with a connected mini-plot (dunno how that would work yet) - but all alternative implementations are welcome.

Comment: In what system? (For example, it's not even clear to me if there's magic or technology available to your players. And some games have mechanics for exactly this type of situation.) Without knowing the system, it's not possible to give a good answer.

Comment: What do you consider sufficient/good engagement? Time spent, interest in - etc. I think there are a few different approaches that work for one kind of engagement and not other kinds.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 18):

### Start the adventure with more characters than players.

This idea draws on the very very early D&D playstyle and the wargaming it originated from. Player characters were practically expected to die and were less super heroes and more just single characters from a company or platoon. So if you expect some 30 to 80% Casualties (Operation Barbarossa and the French invasion of Russia) start with some 9 to 25 characters in the group.

To avoid having to include all of them in one encounter, have them move in platoons of like 5 to 8, split into different tasks like food gathering, scouting, preparing a night camp or something.

This needs some refinement and adapting to the specific campaign and encounters you have planned, but it's the only thing I can come up with to keep enough characters around to keep all the players engaged. In my experience, unless your players are really into the high stakes survival game and are fine with falling out of the core storyline when they die, I don't think an *ad hoc* mechanic to not completely lose a player's interest will be satisfactory for your players.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

### Write a novel

It sounds like a fantastic story. You should write a novel about it.

It sounds like a terrible idea for an RPG where the players turn up to be the protagonists of each and every session. The perfect amount of time for a player to be sidelined for a dead character is exactly equal to the amount of time it takes to make a new character. That’s how long you have to get them back into the game.

Comment: I agree with your idea, but I guess that your delivery of it earns you downvotes.

Comment: Sometimes, the cold hard truth needs to be told. +1

Answer (score 6):

## Have the players take over aspects of the weather

I've done this at times, when I have sessions that are about the environment versus men. You work out some of the moves you could make with the weather and give those over to players. Anyone who dies becomes part of the storm, and gets to try to entice other players out of their loneliness into the warm embrace of death in the storm by freezing to death and becoming part of the storm.

This does require a certain mindset since it's pvp, so you need the right players and buy in from them, but from experience it can be pretty fun.

One system I made was to give the dead players one point per tile of movement. One point could make a minor disturbance, two points a major disturbance, and three points a massive disturbance. They could communicate at will.

So, suppose the players are travelling along the river, and one dies in a surge of the storm. They become part of the rain. The next turn the players are moving through fairly flat land gathering resources, and the dead player just mocks them for abandoning them. The next tile it's rocky terrain, and they decide to unleash two points to make it super slippery. One of the players almost dies, but manages to pull themselves up at the loss of some rations.

The next tile is a muddy tile. They feel a bit sad that they can't do more, because if they had more rain they could make it almost impassable. They do a light drizzle, and slow the players down.

This works pretty well to keep them engaged if they like torturing other players.

Comment: Experienced based answer. +1 

Comment: Useful. That's a variation on the "ghost/shadow" idea I was toying with. The main difference was my "dead" characters would be involved in a struggle with some kind of elemental forces, but trying to support their "alive" comrades rather than "torture" them! I might try giving them the option to do either - perhaps based on alignment.